# Anchor only wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

I am trying to create a *list less* `wp_nav_menu`. Below is the desired output:

```
<nav class="nav header-nav">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-active">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
  <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

I can get pretty close following [Remove LI Elements From Output of wp_nav_menu](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/remove-li-elements-from-output-of-wp_nav_menu/):

```
<nav class="nav header-nav">
<?php
    $menuParameters = array(
      'container'       => false,
      'echo'            => false,
      'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
      'depth'           => 0,
    );
    echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );
?>
</nav>
```

However I can't work out how to add the `nav-link` or `nav-active` classes. I also feel this maybe a little hacky and I should be using a custom `Walker`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you need to add nav-item class or nav-link class?? because in your desired output there is no nav-item class

Comment: @Ammu added the correct class, sorry about that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned in your question that u had removed `li` from the menu. so may be this will work. in this walker u can give the class in the Appearance ->menu css options (On the top right of the screen click on 'Screen Options' on the bottom row - make sure 'CSS Classes' is checked.)

```
    class Class_Name_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
     {
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
     function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 )      {
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

    $class_names = $value = '';

    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $atts = array();
    $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
    $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
    $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
    $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

    $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args );

    $attributes = '';
    foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
        if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
            $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
            $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }
    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .$class_names.'>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
}

/**
 * @see Walker::end_el()
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
 * @param object $item Page data object. Not used.
 * @param int $depth Depth of page. Not Used.
 */
function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "\n";
}
}
```

This walker will add the li classes to a tag. In your theme file (where your wp_nav) is you have to add a [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function).

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new Class_Name_Walker ) );?>
```

**EDIT** :

To add the nav-active class to the current menu item, add this extra filter to functions.php

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if( in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
             $classes[] = 'nav-active ';
     }
     return $classes;
}
```

Comment: But It will add `<li>` which is not required here.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner : i have updated my answer to avoid li from adding to menu

Comment: I guess you forgot to remove from last line.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner: oh..Thanks Rohil ..i forgot to update that.. now i deleted it

Comment: Your welcome . @mikedidthis will know about [custom walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) from your answer .

Comment: @Ammu Thank you for your answer. Sadly I can't hard code `nav-link nav-active` to the homepage link as it won't always be active.

Comment: @mikedidthis: that u can check using current page in the walker

Comment: @Ammu sadly that is where I become stuck. If you could update your answer to reflect my needs, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @mikedidthis: i just edited my answer with a solution to add "nav-active" class. please try it and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Following may be the solution that you are looking for.

```
  <nav><a>
      <?php    
             $defaults = array(
              'container'       => 'false', 
              'echo'            => false,
              'fallback_cb'     => false,
              'items_wrap'      => '<a id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</a>',
              'depth'           => 0
              );
               echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $defaults ));
          ?></a>
    </nav>
```

Edit :

Can you check the above code ? I am not sure about it.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't effect the output.

Comment: Can you tell me what output does it give ? Because I don't have any source to check result.

Comment: The same output as I have now. I believe its technically `<a class="nav-link"><a><a><a></a>` but Chrome / modern browsers won't render nested anchors.