# Output only links using wp_nav_menu()

Tags: php, theme-development, menus

I have been trying to output only links when using the `wp_nav_menu()`. This is because I have a predefined `ul` and `li` tags for the links.

This is what I did:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="drop">
            <?php
                $args  = array(
                    'menu'=>'',
                    'menu_class'=>'',
                    'menu_id'=>'',
                    'container'=>false,
                    'container_class'=>'',
                    'container_id'=>'',
                    'theme_location'=>'header-menu'
                );
                wp_nav_menu($args);
            ?>                          
        </li>
```

Instead I am getting this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="drop">
        <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="">
            <li><a href="http://localhost/shalomcakes/home/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://localhost/shalomcakes/theme/">Theme</a></li>
        </ul>
```

After including this into `functions.php`:

```
function wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter($var) {
    return is_array($var) ? array_intersect($var, array('current-menu-item')) : '';
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
add_filter('page_css_class', 'wp_nav_menu_attributes_filter', 100, 1);
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is exactly. Can you elaborate, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anchor only wp\_nav\_menu](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162409/anchor-only-wp-nav-menu)

Comment: birgire I only want the anchor tags not ul or li

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This should add the drop class to all the li elements in the menu and also add your classes to the wrapping ul:

```
function wpse_232637_add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {       
       $item->classes[] = 'drop';
    }
    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wp_232637_add_menu_parent_class' );



$args  = array(
                'menu'=>'',
                'menu_class'=>'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
                'menu_id'=>'',
                'container'=>false,
                'container_class'=>'',
                'container_id'=>'',
            );

wp_nav_menu($args);
```

Rather than having to strip back all the output of `wp_nav_menu` to use your own `ul` and `li` elements, this should add the classes you want to WP's generated `ul` and `li` elements.